# MVC 3 Razor: Passing data from View using a Model that has classes within it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complex models and partial views - model binding issue in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197038/complex-models-and-partial-views-model-binding-issue-in-mvc3)

Can you pass data from a View to a Controller when the properties are sitting within a class that is within the Model used in that View?

The problem is that when the Submit happens, it seems that properties of my Model 
that belong to a class within that Model do not get populated. 
Properties that are not in classes DO get populated. 
Just think there is a instantiation problem here but not seeing the path forward.

Here is the Model setup:

```
namespace AppName.Models
{
    public class SuperModel
    {
        public SuperModel() {
            SubModA = new SubModelA();
        }
        public string myItem1 { get; set; }
        public SubModelA SubModA { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubModelA
    {
        public string mySubAItem1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
@model AppName.Models.SuperModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page Title";
}

<h2>My Page Title:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NextController", "NextControllerFolder", new { SuperModel = Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @{
        Model.myItem1 = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        Model.SubModA.mySubAItem1 = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.myItem1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubModA.mySubAItem1)

    <p>
        <button name="submit" value="Submit"><b>Continue</b></button>
    </p>
}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NextController(string button, SuperModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // PROBLEM IS HERE>>>
    ///model.myItem1 has a value equal to the current date
    // model.SubModA.mySubAItem1 is null

    return(model);
}
```

Hope this question made sense. Hope the answer is just around the corner! Thanks!

Comment: If I read this correctly -- and it's a bit hard to read -- you are asking about passing Complex Types into a controller specifically when contained within another Complex Type.  It's asked a lot on SO, see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934160/trouble-passing-complex-data-between-view-and-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Could you put your real code? I test it with some changes (for example: I removed the second `@{}` in the view and change  `Model.SubModelA.mySubAItem1` for `Model.SubModA.mySubAItem1`) and it works. Maybe in your real code you omitted some part that you put in you example code.

Comment: You are passing the Type of the property, SubModelA, while you should pass the name of the property that you defined: that is SubModA.

Comment: Thanks all. I corrected the typo in the sample code above. The real code is correct in that regard. Sorry! In reading other posts & docs, the DefaultModelBinder *should* recurse my model and have no problem with the bindings. Others seem to go toward using a custom model binder if that have any trouble. But my hope was to avoid that  since a custom model binder would have to support the recursion encountered with a complex models like this.

Comment: @matthewnreid, Thanks, but in looking at that, the focus was on binding problems associated with a radio-button. Not seeing how that one applies to this, except for workarounds on adding a controller parameter, or reloading the object from the underlying data service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubModA.mySubAItem1)
```

will work.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about the typos in the sample above. Real code was correct. ;(  Have corrected code above...

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line in your code

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubModelA.mySubAItem1)
```

with this one

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubModA.mySubAItem1)
```

Hope this help!